# bash script convert signed hex to signed decimal

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to BASH scripting, but I need a quick way to convert a signed hexadecimal to signed decimal. For instance FF should be -1 not 256. The msbit should be sign bit.

so far I have.. and I need and signed decimal from a signed hex word.

```
#! /bin/sh
ADDR=`echo $1 | tr a-z A-Z`
ADDR2=`echo "ibase=16; obase=10; $ADDR+1" | bc`
VARmsb=`./mpu-6050-getbyte $ADDR;`
VARlsb=`./mpu-6050-getbyte $ADDR2;`
echo  $VARmsb$VARlsb
```

Comment: Would 255 be acceptable instead of -1?

Answer (score 5):

Probably not canonical, but this function should do it:

```
function conv() {
    res=$(printf "%d" "0x$1")
    (( res > 127 )) && (( res -= 256 )) 
    echo $res
}
```

For instance:

```
conv 1
conv 0A
conv 7F
conv 80
conv FF

1
10
127
-128
-1
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
signed_dec=$(printf "%d" $signed_hex)
```

If you need the result to fit inside a certain range then you can apply a modulo operator via [bash arithmetic](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html) e.g:

```
signed_dec=$(($(printf "%d" 0xFAB) % 256))
```

Comment: Does it really work for you? For me, `printf '%d\n' 0xffffffff` gives 4294967295, and `printf '%d\n' 0xffffffffffffffff` gives an overflow error. I'm using bash 4.3.39 (builtin `printf`) and `/usr/bin/printf` from coreutils 8.29 with identical results.